# Attach permissions and groups to custom User model created from BaseUserAdmin

Tags: django

Been at this for a couple of hours and seem to get nowhere. I have a custom User model. In django admin, it is working well but I couldn't find the way to attach the user to groups and individual permissions, as it is done in the default User model of django.

Below is my current code, which is cleaned a bit.

My custom User model is:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email'), unique=True, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('firstName'), max_length=30)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('dateJoined'), auto_now_add=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)



    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'email']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
```

Which is working fine. But in the Admin page, I want to attach/assign a user to a specific group as well as selected permissions, just it is done in the default User model of django.

My admin.py is like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin


from members.forms import UserAdminCreationForm, UserAdminChangeForm
from members.models import User


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm


    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('first_name', 'email',
                    'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'status')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('email', 'first_name',
                                     'is_staff')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff',)})
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name',  'is_staff')}
         ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name')
    ordering = ('first_name',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from members.models import User


class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','first_name','is_staff')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("email is taken")
        return email




class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','first_name','is_staff')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('is_staff','first_name', 'display_name' )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff','groups', 'user_permissions')})

Add the above 2 fields in admin.py